# How to serialize the following Json into this format

Tags: json

```
[{
    "sicCode":null,
    "postCode":null,
    "isGeneratorFacility":"Y",
    "isCustomer":null,
    "externalID":"0011l00000NSrR1AAL",
    "companyName":"AccountName1",
    "businessDescription":"Big Business HO2",
    "address4":"United Kingdom",
    "address3":null,
    "address2":null,
    "address1":null
}]
```

I want to append square bracket (`[`) at the begining of JSON and in the end of it, so that I can pass it into API callout. And also please let me know if that's possible - whenever I am trying to concat square brckt it says `'{' expected` in debug console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a corresponding class having all the attributes from json like below

```
Public class serializeObject{
    public string sicCode;
    public string postCode;
    public string isGeneratorFacility;
    public string externalID;
    .......
    .......
}
```

Then serialize your json like this

```
List<serializeObject> objserialize = (list<serializeObject>)JSON.deserialize(yourJsonHere, list<serializeObject>.class );
```

Comment: But it's not creating the array at the begining and ending of the json structure. I had tried the code above already..

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Bad request, and it's neither working in postman but when I am appending '[' at both side of json then it's returning the id. So that's why I thought I should write in this way in apex class too..

Comment: From where you are getting this JSON? Have you tried appending [ through code and then pass the json to serialize?

Comment: @Samir They just need to make a *list* of the wrapper class, then use that instead.

Comment: I have tried to append it manually but that's not ideal approach. So should I just take list of wrapper..

Comment: Yes. Just take a wrapper and then you should be good.i have updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

Create a wrapper class for your object, such as @Samir suggested, but also serialise/deserialise as a list.

```
List<SerializeObject> wrapperList = new List<SerializeObject>();
wrapperList.add(yourData);

String jsonString = JSON.serialize(wrapperList);
// [{"sicCode":"foo", "postCode":"bar", ...}]
```

The square brackets you're looking for mean that you're passing a list of JSON objects. Reflect that accordingly in APEX and it should serialize/deserialize to your needs.

As a point of good practice, it might be worthwhile asking why a list is needed in your use-case - especially if it's the case that there must always be one element (no more, no less).